# React hooks cannot map array within JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I've really searched in many places of the internet and cannot for the life of me find a solution around my problem.

I'm unable to map through an array within my React's JSX. I've been able to do it in the past effortlessly but for some reason, when I decided to practice some React Hooks, things got way too tricky.

Here is my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

const Search = () => {

// takes information written in input field.
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const lookUp = e.target.value;
    setSearchTerm(lookUp);
    return lookUp;
  };

  // useState for searcing the term in the search box
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  // useState for submitting the form and getting a result
    const [word, setWord] = useState("")
    const [definitions, setDefinitions] = useState("")


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const apiKey = "secretsecret";
    const apiURL = `https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/thesaurus/json/${searchTerm}?key=${apiKey}`;
      e.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: apiURL,
      dataResponse: "json",
    }).then((res) => {

        res.data.map(wordInfo => {

            const wordArray = Object.values(wordInfo)
            setWord(wordInfo.hwi.hw)

            if (wordInfo.hwi.hw === searchTerm) {

                const defsArray = wordInfo.shortdef;

                setDefinitions(defsArray)

                const syns = wordInfo.meta.syns;
                syns.map(synWords => {
                    synWords.map(wordsLol => {


                    })
                })
            }
        })
    });
  };

return (
  <div>
    <div className="searchForm">

      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="searchBox">Look up a word</label>
        <input type="text" id="searchBox" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search me!" />
      </form>
    </div>
        <div className="wordInfo">
            {definitions.map(test => {
                console.log(test)
            })}
        </div>
  </div>
);
};

export default Search;
```

Don't mind the lame variable names, this is just my practice project.

Any input would definitely be helpful. What do I seem to be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

initialize empty array here:

```
const [definitions, setDefinitions] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Except init `definitions` as array to prevent mapping a string as @Nilanka Manoj stated, when you render HTML syntax after `map`, make sure you have put `return`. For example:

```
<div className="wordInfo">
            {definitions.map(test => {
                return (
                   //your HTML syntax
                )
            })}
</div>
```

or you can do sth like this

```
<div className="wordInfo">
            {definitions.map(test => (
                   //your HTML syntax
            ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `searchTerm` in `handleSubmit` which refer to a closure value. React won't update `handleSubmit` function every time render, so you always get old value of `searchTerm` which is empty when user click.

You could use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and add `searchTerm` as dependencies

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    const apiKey = "secretsecret";
    const apiURL = `https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/thesaurus/json/${searchTerm}?key=${apiKey}`;
      e.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: apiURL,
      dataResponse: "json",
    }).then((res) => {

        res.data.map(wordInfo => {

            const wordArray = Object.values(wordInfo)
            setWord(wordInfo.hwi.hw)

            if (wordInfo.hwi.hw === searchTerm) {

                const defsArray = wordInfo.shortdef;

                setDefinitions(defsArray)

                const syns = wordInfo.meta.syns;
                syns.map(synWords => {
                    synWords.map(wordsLol => {


                    })
                })
            }
        })
    });
  }, [searchTerm]);
```